# Can I subscribe to a tag on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, subscription

Is there any way to subscribe to emails for a tag from an iPhone or iPad? The option doesn't seem to available in the iOS app or mobile site?

If it isn't available, can this feature be added to the iOS app?