# Subscribe to tags via app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, subscription

I could not see any easy way to subscribe to tags in a group.  I tried long-pressing the tag but nothing appears.

Any ideas?

Comment: Such feature does not exist. [Same request for iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300871/can-i-subscribe-to-a-tag-on-mobile).